# Use PNG external graphic for vector layer with OpenLayers 5.3

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer, png, mviewer

I am currently working on a webmapping project using Mviewer device, linked to OpenLayers 5.3. I am trying to create a new vector layer to locate points, with js. So far, I managed to create a layer with circles and colours categorizing the types of objects I want to represent. What I would like to do is to replace the representations with coloured circles by customized PNG mapmarkers which I found online. But I still cannot find the way to insert external graphics for my representation. Here is my code block:

```
{
mviewer.customLayers.bati_officiel = {};
 var categorie = mviewer.customLayers.bati_officiel;

 categorie.legend = { items: [
{
    label: "Culturel",
    geometry: "Point",
    styles: [ new ol.style.Style({
   image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(218,221,225,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "#ffffff",
        width: 4
    }),
    radius: 9
   })
  })]
 },   
{
    label: "Equipement public",
    geometry: "Point",
    styles: [new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(27,132,237,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "#ffffff",
        width: 4
    }),
    radius: 9
  })
})]
 },
  {
    label: "Marine",
    geometry: "Point",
    styles: [new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(237,27,27,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "#ffffff",
        width: 4
    }),
    radius: 9
  })
})]
 },
  {
    label: "Religieux",
    geometry: "Point",
    styles: [new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(27,200,27,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "#ffffff",
        width: 4
    }),
    radius: 9
  })
 })]
 },
   {
    label: "Scolaire",
    geometry: "Point",
    styles: [new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(69,120,27,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "#ffffff",
        width: 4
    }),
    radius: 9
  })
})]
 },
  {
    label: "Social",
    geometry: "Point",
    styles: [new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(59,30,217,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "#ffffff",
        width: 4
    }),
    radius: 9
    })
  })]
  },
    {
    label: "Sportif",
    geometry: "Point",
    styles: [new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(218,20,27,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "#ffffff",
        width: 4
    }),
    radius: 9
  })
 })]
 }

] };


    mviewer.customLayers.bati_officiel.layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "https://extranet.ville-houilles.fr/geoserver/houillesSIG/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=houillesSIG:bati_officiel&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson",
         format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
     }),
     style: function(feature, resolution) {
        var stl;            
        if (feature.get('categorie')) {           
            switch (feature.get('categorie')) {
                 case "Culturel":
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[0].styles;
                    break;
                case "Equipement public":
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[1].styles;
                    break;
                case "Marine":
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[2].styles;
                    break;
               case "Religieux":
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[3].styles;
                    break;
                case "Scolaire":
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[4].styles;
                    break;      
                case "Social":
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[5].styles;
                    break;      
                case "Sportif":
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[6].styles;
                    break;                              
                default:
                    stl = categorie.legend.items[0].styles;
            }
        }            
        return stl;
    }
 });
mviewer.customLayers.bati_officiel.handle = false;

}
```

Here is a link to my project if needed : [enter link description here](https://extranet.ville-houilles.fr/mviewer/Carte_de_la_ville_de_Houilles_leitao.html#)

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the solution quite quickly ! Here is a sample to what I did with a piece of my code :
This part :

```
{
label: "Equipement public",
geometry: "Point",
styles: [new ol.style.Style({
     image: new ol.style.Circle({
fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(27,132,237,1.0)'
}),
stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "#ffffff",
    width: 4
}),
radius: 9
  })
})]
 }
```

Became this :

```
 {
    label: "Equipement public",
    geometry: "Point",
     styles: [new ol.style.Style({
           image: new ol.style.Icon({
anchor: [0, 0],
src: 'https://extranet.ville-houilles.fr/mviewer/png_test/office-building.png'
  })
})]
  }
```

Now it works great !